# How to adjust output voltage of boost/buck converter ic's?

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I've been looking to create a circuit with variable voltage output. I've looked at linear regulators such as the LM317 but this cannot handle higher currents so I turned my attention to switching regulators. However these seem to be much more complicated, for example the LTC3895 (http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3895fa.pdf) or LTC7812. I have no idea how you would adjust the voltage with a simple potentiometer. I believe the LTC3780 is quite easy in this regard however. Can someone explain how I could control the voltage of these ic's?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the two resistors forming a potential divider connected to the "VFB" pin on page 1 of that datasheet. Read about what that pin does.

Comment: 1) All these chips have **two resistors in series** between the **output** and **ground**. That's the **feedback voltage divider**, the divided voltage is fed to the **feedback input** of the chip. This is described in the datasheets. 2) Unless you have experience with switched mode regulators or access to someone who has, I would urge you **not** to build your own circuit. Instead use a cheap module like an LM2596 based module. These are cheaper than the components bought separately and will just **work**. For hobby projects, these are ideal.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the voltage is controlled by feedback into the IC. If you read the datasheet of any IC it will usually give you a description of what each pin does. If we go with the example of your IC, the LTC3895, witht he datasheet you linked, you will eventually come across this section: [image]

This tells you exactly how to set the output voltage. This particular equation should look familiar. If you recognise the equation, you will realise how the voltage is set. If we were to look at a linear adjustable regulator, such as the LM317, we see this in the datasheet: [image]

It's the same equation. This is because the voltage is adjusted in the same way, the switching regulator just has extra bits to increase efficiency. The basic feedback circuit for this is essentially a simple op amp circuit like this:[image]

Your Fb pin is the inverting input of the op amp and your Vref is set internally (0.8V in the case of the LTC3895). If you know op amps, you will know that it will adjust it's output to try and keep both inputs the same. By changing the feedback resistors, this changes the feedback voltage which in turn forces the op amp to adjust it's output.

As you can see, the simple answer is change the resistors and you can control the output. If you stick a potentiometer in your feedback loop, then you can control it with that.

**NOTE:** This answer is just from my personal knowledge so if I have provided any incorrect information, feel free to let me know so I can change it, and feel free to add anything I have missed out too.